# usages of comma- why do we need the third and fourth commas?

Tags: commas, relative-clauses

There are four commas in the following sentence. Could you please review if they used commas correctly? Why do they need the **third and fourth commas**? What would happen otherwise? If you can explain with some examples, it would be reall helpful.

"Without that acknowledgment, hermeneutic thematization could not offer, and thereby would prevent **,** the practitioner from recognizing **,** any reconfiguring of his or her assumptions."

Source- I got this line from a book on art theory.

Thanks for your time and help. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you check your source again? The comma after _prevent_ is quite curious.

Comment: @KarlG yes, it's correct. you can copy and paste the whole line on google. you will find the source.  I am thinking that without comma after **prevent** , **could not offer** won't read its object correctly. Maybe I am wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Without that acknowledgment, hermeneutic thematization could not offer, and thereby would prevent, the practitioner from recognizing, any reconfiguring of his or her assumptions.

This is a sentence which has escaped the author's control and the watchful eye of a decent editor. It looks like the author intended a compound verb in parallel structure, *offer* and *would prevent*, only to discover after slapping down a comma that these two verbs do not have the same object, leaving *the practitioner from recognizing* as utter nonsense flapping in the breeze. The *reconfiguring* is, in fact, the direct object of both *offer* and the gerund-participle *recognizing*.

Thus the following is the case:

> Hermeneutic thematization could not offer any reconfiguring of assumptions.
>
> Hermeneutic thematization would thereby prevent the practitioner from recognizing any reconfiguration of assumptions.

The comma after *prevent* inexplicably separates it from its predicate.

At the very least the sentence should be punctuated:

> Without that acknowledgment, hermeneutic thematization could not offer, and thereby would prevent the practitioner from recognizing, any reconfiguring of his or her assumptions.

Better would be:

> Without that acknowledgment, hermeneutic thematization could not offer — and thereby would prevent the practitioner from recognizing — any reconfiguring of his or her assumptions.

Comment: may I know what why we would need last comma? or if we could remove the last comma. Thanks again.